# Some modules use code versions newer or older than the database. First update the module code, then run 'setup:upgrade'

Tags: upgrade, magento-2.0.7

The module code base doesn't match the DB schema and data.

Magento_Theme             schema:       2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_Theme             data:         2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_Customer          schema:       2.0.9  ->  2.0.6
Magento_Customer          data:         2.0.9  ->  2.0.6
 Magento_Cms              schema:       2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
 Magento_Cms              data:         2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_Catalog           schema:       2.1.3  ->  2.0.3
Magento_Catalog           data:         2.1.3  ->  2.0.3
Magento_Search            schema:       2.0.4  ->  2.0.1
Magento_Search            data:         2.0.4  ->  2.0.1
Magento_Quote             schema:       2.0.3  ->  2.0.2
Magento_Quote             data:         2.0.3  ->  2.0.2
Magento_Msrp              schema:       2.1.3  ->  2.0.0
Magento_Msrp              data:         2.1.3  ->  2.0.0
Magento_Bundle            schema:       2.0.2  ->  2.0.1
Magento_Bundle            data:         2.0.2  ->  2.0.1
Magento_Downloadable      schema:       2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_Downloadable      data:         2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_Sales             schema:       2.0.3  ->  2.0.1
Magento_Sales             data:         2.0.3  ->  2.0.1
Magento_CatalogInventory  schema:       2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_CatalogInventory  data:         2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_GroupedProduct    schema:       2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_GroupedProduct    data:         2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_Integration       schema:       2.2.0  ->  2.0.1
Magento_Integration       data:         2.2.0  ->  2.0.1
Magento_CatalogRule       schema:       2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_CatalogRule       data:         2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_SalesRule         schema:       2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_SalesRule         data:         2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_Swatches          schema:       2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_Swatches          data:         2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_GiftMessage       schema:       2.0.1  ->  2.0.0
Magento_GiftMessage       data:         2.0.1  ->  2.0.0

Some modules use code versions newer or older than the database. 
First update the module code, then run `'setup:upgrade'`.

Comment: have you run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` ?

Comment: Yes , Run that command nothing is upgrade